Measure for calculating the previous year's revenue in an accumulated manner
I am trying to create a line chart that compares three different measures.
Light blue line - referring to the accumulated revenue until the current month.
Dark blue line - referring to the accumulated target until the current month.
The orange line should be the revenue realized in the previous year, but I am having trouble applying a condition that does not display the same value for the other months.

For the accumulated revenue of the current year, I used the following measures
    Faturamento Realizado = 
    
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(tb_Base_Faturamento[FATURAMENTO LÍQUIDO])
        ,'tb_Base_Faturamento'[VISÃO] = "REAL"
    )


    Faturamento Yeartodate Atual = 
    VAR FinalMesAtual = 
    [Final Mes Atual]
    
    RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        TOTALYTD(
            [Faturamento Realizado],
            tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data],
            "30/06"
        ),
    
            FILTER(
                tb_Calendario_Faturamento,
                tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data] <= FinalMesAtual
            )
            
    )

And that worked correctly
When I try to apply the same logic for the previous year, I can't implement a condition that restricts the orange line only up to the current month.
    AnoAnteriorFaturamentoYeartodate = 
    VAR FinalMesAtualAnoAnterior =
        CALCULATE(
            MAX(tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data]),
            MONTH(tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data]) = MONTH(TODAY()) &&
            YEAR(tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data]) = YEAR(TODAY()) - 1
        )
    
    RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        [Faturamento Realizado],
        FILTER(
            ALL(tb_Calendario_Faturamento),
            tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data] <= FinalMesAtualAnoAnterior
        ),
        SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(DATESYTD(tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data],"30/06"))
    )
    

I tried various ways and always end up with the same result, either not calculating anything.
Any suggestions?

You need to calculate the maximum date for the same month as the current year but in the previous year.
With FILTER, the calculation is only done for dates in the previous year up to the same month as the current year.
Then TOTALYTD will calculate the year-to-date total for the previous year, and the filter will make it restricted to dates up to the calculated FinalMesAtualAnoAnterior :
AnoAnteriorFaturamentoYeartodate = 
VAR FinalMesAtualAnoAnterior = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data]),
        YEAR(tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data]) = YEAR(TODAY()) - 1 &&
        MONTH(tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data]) <= MONTH(TODAY()) 
    )
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    TOTALYTD(
        [Faturamento Realizado],
        tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data],
        "30/06"
    ),
    FILTER(
        ALL(tb_Calendario_Faturamento),
        tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data] <= FinalMesAtualAnoAnterior &&
        YEAR(tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data]) = YEAR(TODAY()) - 1
    )
)


HI @Amira Bedhiafi, Thank you for the support, I had already tried a solution similar to yours. The graph shows a flat line with the same value for all months.

Can you share some data ? and your model ?

Last night, I was working on this measure. I managed to solve it without needing to change the model.

AnoAnteriorFaturamentoYeartodate =
VAR FinalMesAtualAnoAnterior =
CALCULATE(
MAX(tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data]),
YEAR(tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data]) = YEAR(TODAY()) - 1 &&
MONTH(tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data]) <= MONTH(TODAY())
)
RETURN
CALCULATE(
[Faturamento Acumulado Atual],
SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data]),
tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data] <= FinalMesAtualAnoAnterior
)

I was able to solve the issue using the measure for the current year as a base and using the SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR function with a filter:
AnoAnteriorFaturamentoYeartodate = 

VAR FinalMesAtualAnoAnterior = 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX(tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data]),
        YEAR(tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data]) = YEAR(TODAY()) - 1 &&
        MONTH(tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data]) <= MONTH(TODAY()) 
    )

RETURN
CALCULATE(    
    [Faturamento Acumulado Atual],
    SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data])
    ,tb_Calendario_Faturamento[Data]<=FinalMesAtualAnoAnterior
)

